# unable to use datetimepicker with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, datetimepicker

Trying to use the datetimepicker addon.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css">

<script>
 $(function() {
$("#datentime").datetimepicker();
// $("#datentime").datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="content">
    <input type="text" name="datentime" id="datentime" value="" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my jsfiddle -
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckKtn/24/)

The datetimepicker does not work if jquery mobile is selected. I think this is the best date and time picker and would love to get it working with jquery mobile. Has anyone gotten this to work in mobile?

PS. I have also tried using jquery-1.10 without any luck.

TIA.
RD

Answer (score 0):

just made a datetimepicker for jquerymobile for both date and time in one UI

https://github.com/ngethe/jQM-DateBoxNgethe